# Codeigniter - using session data in view

Tags: codeigniter, session, variables

I have a users first and last name stored in session data and I want to echo it out in the view so they can see who they are logged in as. I can't seem to get the data to pass. I'm sure this is something easy but I'm pretty new to CI and the whole MVC thing.

Controller Code:

```
public function index() {
    if($this->session->userdata('admin_signed_in')){
    $this->load->model('dashboard_model');
    $data['userdata'] = $this->session->userdata;
    $data['main_content'] = 'dashboard/dashboard';  
    $this->load->view('common/template', $data);
    } else {
    redirect('signin');
    }

}
```

View Code:

```
<?php echo $userdata('first_name') ?>  <?php echo $userdata('last_name') ?>
```

Print R Results:

```
Array ( [session_id] => 69db0f9ccbfde96d92cc09837067438c [ip_address] => ::1 [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0 [last_activity] => 1352998508 [user_data] => [0] => Array ( [admin_id] => 10 [first_name] => Richard [last_name] => Coy [admin_role] => 1 ) [admin_signed_in] => 1 )
```

Comment: You are using `$userdata` variable in a function format (using parantheses) while this is a variable and in your case is an array! try using `$userdata['firstname']` instead

Comment: `echo $this->session->userdata('your_session_name');`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Controller code:

```
public function index() {

    ...
    $data['first_name'] = $this->session->userdata('first_name');
    ...
}
```

View code:

```
<?= $first_name; ?>
```

OR, if you want to pass the data like you currently are, you would access the view data userdata as an array, not a function, ie:

```
<?= $userdata['first_name'];?>
```

Comment: Nothing is getting passed to the view using the code you provided. I've added the print_r results to show that the data is there.

Comment: What is contained within `$data['first_name']` after you assign the userdata to it?

Comment: I don't know how to check that.

Comment: I can hard code a value and it gets passed and displayed in the view. Something must be wrong with the session.

Comment: I had several other problems with my session code. After I got those fixed your code worked. Thanks. This CI stuff is cool but also difficult to grasp at first.

Comment: Cool - just out of curiosity - what were your session code problems?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments , when you assign a value to array `$data` and pass it through Codeigniter view loader , the data will be available in the view part with variable names same to the array indexes.
for example when you do this:

```
$data['name'] = "bla bla";
$this->load->view('some_view', $data);
```

then the `$name` variable in the view will contain your passed value. In your case you are assigning an array to `$data['userdata']`. so the `$userdata` in the view will an array too.

So do like this:

```
echo $userdata['firstname'];
echo $userdata['lastname'];
```

in the view part.